# Describing the image of the complex set $G = \{ z = x+iy \mid x^2 + y^2 + 2x + 2y + 1 = 0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G = \{ z = x+iy \mid x^2 + y^2 + 2x + 2y + 1 = 0\}$, $f(z) = \frac{2z+3}{z+i}$

I wish to describe the image of the set $G$. However, I am not sure how to apply the restriction to $f$. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: $G$ is a circle, $f$ is a Möbius map. What do Möbius maps do to circles?

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

- Note $G$ is a circle and find three different points on it.
- Remember Möbius transformations (such as $f$) take generalised circles (usual circles or straight lines) to generalised circles. Hence you only need to know the image of three points.

Comment: So, find three points that satisfy $G$. So, $x=0, y=-1$, $x=-1, y=0$, and $x=-2, y=-1$. $f$ is a mobius transform and has a unique mapping from three points to another three points. So, we find what $f$ is per those three points, then we have another circle!

Comment: So I find three points in G, (0,-1),(-1,0),(-2,-1). For the first point f(z = 0 - i) = (2(-1) +3)/(-i + i) =  -2+3/0. Division by 0. Do we say that f = infinity? Then $f(-1) = \frac{1}{-1 + i}$, $f(2-i) = \frac{-2 - i + 3}{-1 + i}$. We a point that maps to infinity. How do I now check if these three points lie on a line or a circle?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the circle as $$|z+1+i|=1$$ and we can write $$w=u+iv=\frac{2z+3}{z+i}\Rightarrow z=\frac{3-iw}{w-2}$$
Substituting, we get $$\left|\frac{3-iw}{w-2}+1+i\right|=1$$
$$\Rightarrow |w+1-2i|=|w-2|$$
$$\Rightarrow(u+1)^2+(v-2)^2=(u-2)^2+v^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 6u-4v+1=0$$
So the image is a straight line

Comment: I would rather take advantage of using mobius transformations. If you know the answer my confusion regarding that, in the comments of the answer, please let me know